# Node.JS variable outside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, if-statement

I am using mongodb and mongoose in node.js
Inside the function, it verifies the username and password.
user.password works inside the first if statement, but after that in the if else below, where the user actually comes into play it returns.

```
              if (password1 == user.password) {
                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null
```

The code that I have is.

```
User.findOne({ 'Username: ': username1}, function(err, user) {
    if (err){
        console.log("There was an error proccesing the request".red + " : ".red + err);
    } else if (user == '') {
        console.log("This user was not found")

    } else {
      prompt('Password: ', function(password1){
          if (password1 == user.password) {

              console.log("User Login Sucsess")
          } else {

              console.log("Password incorrect")
              proccess.exit();
          }


          console.log("made it");


      })

    }
})
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue

Thank you!

Comment: No such `user` is found, but the test for "not found" isn't succeeding. `user` will either be `null` or a document `Object`. In either case,, `user == ''` will be false. `null` is only `==` to itself or `undefined` and an object compared to a string will be first converted to a string, resulting in -- `"[object Object]" == "" // false`.

Comment: What is `prompt()` in node.js code?

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding, how would I correct this?

Comment: You might want to consider hashing the passwords.

Comment: Passwords are already hashed in the database, I have not hashed the users input yet to compare with database password.

when I console.log the response from user I get,

>{ _id: 560734a53e04afd4029ab020,
  username: 'archlinuxusa',
  password: '9cb1e3525d22f14efd',
  server: 'ftb',
  admin: true,
  __v: 0 }

Comment: So its not like the variable does not exist, for some reason it disappears outside of the scope of the first if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't necessarily anything wrong with the line that's throwing the error:

```
if (password1 == user.password) {
```

This is more so where the issue becomes certain. The root of the issue is a few lines up:

```
} else if (user == '') {
    console.log("This user was not found")
```

The error message is suggesting that `user` is `null` (because `null` cannot have properties like `.password`), meaning in this case that no document was found matching the query. But, the condition isn't catching this, allowing the function to continue to execute beyond it and attempt to read `user.password` when there isn't a `user`.

This is because `null == ''` is `false`. In JavaScript, the `null` value is only `==` to itself or `undefined`.

```
var user = null;
console.log(user == '');        // false

console.log(null == '');        // false
console.log(null == null);      // true
console.log(null == undefined); // true
```

Adjusting the condition to check for `null` specifically should resolve this:

```
} else if (user == null) {
    console.log("This user was not found")
```

Comment: When using this method, it breaks the whole script, when I debugged it, the server was able to find the username that the user entered, but for some reason even though the script was able to find my user in the database it sent me to "this user was not found", when it used to send me to the next prompt for the password

Comment: @ChristopherKemp Note that you appear to possibly have a typo in the query, having a space and colon as characters within the property name -- `'Username: '`.

Comment: upon assessing the username issue in the query, and entering a known username in the table.
Whats your name?>archlinuxusa
scs
>This user was not found

Comment: There was a few issues with my code, and my statements, the issue was related to the way I was assessing what you said above, and the way I was using the findOne function.

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The error message `Cannot read property 'password' of null` indicates that `user` is `null`. But the code is checking for empty string. Check for `null` instead or in addition. For example, instead of...:

```
} else if (user == '') {
```

...do something more like this:

```
} else if (! user) {
```

`! user` will be true if `user` is empty string or `null` or any [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: Okay the issue isn't with the username spectrum.  its with the password section of this code, if I could somehow just get the array of variables from user from the first section, so when the user is asked for his password with the prompt function it can successfully verify the response with what is in mongodb. here is my whole code http://jsfiddle.net/L3taw280/

Comment: The error message indicates that `user` is `null` and that the program is blowing up when you try to check `user.password` because you are trying to read the `password` property of `null` which you cannot do. The error is that you think you are validating that `user` has been successfully retrieved, but it has not been.